# How combine two fields to one object in mongoDB using spring MongoTemplate?

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation

How should look `project()` in `newAggregation()` when I want to get two combined fields? My collection contains three fields: a, b, c. Script in JS looks like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
        $project:
            {
                "a": "$a",
                "new_field": {
                    "b": "$b",
                    "c": "$c"
                }
            }
    })
```

Comment: Does the answer help you

Answer (score 0):

Few methods we can't acheive using spring data, but solution is

```
 Aggregation aggregation=newAggregation(
    p-> new Document("$project",
        new Document()
        .append("a","$a"),
        .append("new_field",
            new Document("b","$b")
            .append("c","$c"),
        )
     )
 )
```